# How to retrieve data after a specific child in firebase?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

if i connect to firebase again after my connection was terminated when it is reestablished  `FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded` type observer was reinitialised, my problem is that i receive all child nodes again from first instead i want child after a specific child key. i am keeping track for last child key in my `NSUserDefaults`.

[image: My firebase structure]

i have my `FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded` on locations and i want locations after key `-KbyxQDkWMeqEFQw8Bm5`, what i receive is all locations again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C

```
FIRDatabaseQuery *query = [[ref queryOrderedByKey] queryStartingAtValue:lastChildKey];

[query observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeChildAdded
                          withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
                          }
                    withCancelBlock:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
                    }];
```

Swift

```
let query = ref.queryOrderedByKey().queryStarting(atValue: lastChildKey)

query(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in })
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply but i tried it and it didn't work it is returning me value for timestamp key inside my child

Comment: your reference must be to locations branch.